# DC power jack socket footprint

Tags: dc, connector, standard

Is there a standard that all DC power jacks follow? More specifically, I plan to use 5.5/2.1 mm barrel, and I've found a bunch of these components on eBay, but they all lack drawings (not to mention 3D models).

I've found a 3D model, but it does not fit to a footprint of one commercial component that I've managed to find. And that is why I'm asking for a standard.

For example, this component

http://www.gravitech.us/poja2x51.html

does not have a drawing, they only state that it follows the **IEC 60130-10 Standard**, but I wasn't able to find drawings for this standard.

Comment: Buy parts with a complete datasheet.  They probably cost more than if you buy them off ebay, but you save hours of your time trying to figure out how to use them.  If you have already bought a pile of them, then measure the parts yourself.

Comment: Some connectors are std. but patents or copy protections on mold may affect design and footprint. More important is rugged design choice and spring quality of contact for retention force. So if you choose poorly guess what your quality becomes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard footprint for a DC jack connector.
There are too many variants of this connector out there.
You can have round holes, SMD, slots, switched pin on the right or on the left.

As JRE commented, get the manufacturer's datasheet and use the recommended footprint.

If there is no footprint in that datasheet, next time buy from a higher quality manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

The standard requires you to pay money to get a legitimate copy. In any case, it would cover the mating surfaces etc. to assure interoperability not the mounting surfaces.

You are best off to pick a part such as CUI [PJ-202A](https://www.cui.com/product/resource/pj-202a.pdf) which conforms to a **de-facto** standard, in that there are many similar and interoperable products available from  various sources including many Chinese factories. That way when (if) you go to mass production the part may cost 1/10 of what a proprietary part might cost. As to how you tell which are the de-facto standards, you have to query mass manufacturers for their data and/or visit factories and get their drawings (they **all** have drawings for approval, but often disreputable resellers don't bother supplying them). For small quantities just stick with reputable sources and datasheets. 
[image]